# How to interpolate variables that are within a file on remote machine via Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a config file on the remote machine in the format:

```
key1={{key1}}
key2={{key2}}
```

I want to use Ansible to populate the values of the keys with values from group_vars.

How can I read this file in, interpolate the contents, and write the file back out?

I don't want to use templates since different config files will have different keys, and my understanding of templates is that i'd have to know in advance which keys I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are (but I don't think this is how you should manage systems):

```
---
- hosts: target
  vars:
    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2"
  tasks:
    - command: cat /path/to/file
      register: cat_file
    - copy:
        content: "{{ cat_file.stdout }}\n"
        dest: /path/to/file
```

<sup>There is a problem with the trailing newline character, which is not reflected in the `stdout` from `cat`. I assumed it should be added.</sup>

Alternatively:

```
---
- hosts: target
  vars:
    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2"
  tasks:
    - fetch:
        src: /path/to/file
        dest: ./tmp/file
    - template:
        src: ./tmp/file
        dest: /path/to/file
```

Comment: with the first proposed solution, my output file has the following contents:

Comment: key1={#key1#} \n key2={#key2#} . why are those hash marks getting put in there and why doesnt the interpolation work?

Comment: How can I know? I'm not sitting in front of your computer. I tested with Ansible 2.2.2 and it did not escape the strings. If it does not work for you, you should explain why, not me. Besides, I was not particularly fond of this, so I have suggested the second, more reliable method.

Comment: your second solution does work for me, and i will mark your answer correct.